# How do i convert this cURL command into PHP code? And what is "Request Payload"?

Tags: php, curl, networking, cookies, upload

So, I was inspecting the network while I'm uploading an JPG image.

[image]

A copy as a curl command :

```
curl "https://admin-official.line.me/11702069/home/api/objects" -H "Origin: https://admin-official.line.me" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,id;q=0.8,de-DE;q=0.7,de;q=0.6" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryBv1B9k1i89zlgjnA" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Referer: https://admin-official.line.me/11702069/home/send/" -H "Cookie: tzoffset=-420; _trmccid=6b030cba93d9db09; _ga=GA1.2.1058855825.1526457491; _gid=GA1.2.814129237.1526457491; ldsuid=CiDum1r75zWBJ3f7oLqRAg==; _trmcdisabled2=-1; _trmcuser=^{^\^"id^\^":^\^"^\^"^}; _ga=GA1.3.1058855825.1526457491; _gid=GA1.3.814129237.1526457491; plack_session_localaccount=XXX; minesota=XXX; minesota2=XXX-jdT5f_x10ov7Re12NliQw_zFyIe9osY4oOOc2Rxdy1gMyBhXbKdPmnpA2LHB9VhvlqlL_4hkeSNQK5SgU; plack_session=6cd2e4790ae9990303ea54f7f35b305fba801dc0; _trmcsession=^{^\^"id^\^":^\^"b8ba0724^\^",^\^"path^\^":^\^"/11702069/home/send/^\^",^\^"query^\^":^\^"^\^",^\^"time^\^":1526735963213,^\^"_dice^\^":0.09452730791211028^}; __try__=1526737592637; _trmcpage=/11702069/home/send/" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --data-binary ^"------WebKitFormBoundaryBv1B9k1i89zlgjnA^

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=^\^"file^\^"; filename=^\^"alpen.jpg^\^"^

Content-Type: image/jpeg^

^

^

------WebKitFormBoundaryBv1B9k1i89zlgjnA^

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=^\^"csrf_token^\^"^

^

vJiSf8AZPpAvqCp0JQtrNOMgrZRtrDpa1TEHbYLz^

------WebKitFormBoundaryBv1B9k1i89zlgjnA--^

^" --compressed
```

I've never seen this before, i'm not an expert at curl. But I'm using [curl to PHP coverter](https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/), but it's not working in this case.

EDIT : here's what I've tried.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://admin-official.line.me/11702069/home/api/objects");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("file" => "@".realpath('test.jpg'), "csrf_token" => $split2[0]));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Origin: https://admin-official.line.me";
$headers[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br";
$headers[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,id;q=0.8,de-DE;q=0.7,de;q=0.6";
$headers[] = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryBv1B9k1i89zlgjnA";
$headers[] = "Accept: */*";
$headers[] = "Referer: https://admin-official.line.me/11702069/home/send/";
$headers[] = 'Cookie: tzoffset=-420; _trmccid=6b030cba93d9db09; _ga=GA1.2.1058855825.1526457491; _gid=GA1.2.814129237.1526457491; ldsuid=CiDum1r75zWBJ3f7oLqRAg==; _trmcdisabled2=-1; _trmcuser={"id":""}; _ga=GA1.3.1058855825.1526457491; _gid=GA1.3.814129237.1526457491; plack_session_localaccount=XXX; minesota=XXX; minesota2=XXX; plack_session=XXX; _trmcsession={"id":"b8ba0724","path":"/11702069/home/send/","query":"","time":1526735963213,"_dice":0.09452730791211028}; __try__=1526737592637; _trmcpage=/11702069/home/send/';
$headers[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Just a heads up. The cookie you so carefully obscured on the network log screenshot is shown in plain text in the curl command you posted.

Comment: You should have really given an example of the PHP you tried rather than expecting us to write it from scratch for you.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I've add it. I just don't know how to dealt with this.

Comment: use guzzle instead.

Answer (score 2):

the "request payload" is the **request body**. a HTTP request is split into 2 parts, the **headers**, and the **body** (and Chrome calls the body for the request payload here, not sure if that's an official name, or just the whim of a chromium dev)

anyway, you're using the `@` method, which was discouraged as of PHP 5.5, disabled-by-default in php 5.6, and completely removed in PHP7.

use `CURLFile` instead, eg:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    "file" => new CURLFile('test.jpg'),
    "csrf_token" => $split2[0]
));
```

also, don't set the **Accept-Encoding** header manually. you specify **gzip, deflate, br**, and `curl` doesn't support **br**, and depending on how `libcurl` was compiled, might not even support gzip/deflate (although it usually does), remove that.

also, set `CURLOPT_ENCODING` to `emptystring`, and `curl` will list all encodings it was built to support (which is usually **gzip** and **deflate**, but is not guaranteed to be)

also, when using the `@` or `CURLFile` method, don't set the **Content-Type** header manually, because if curl's boundary doesn't match what you set in the **Content-Type** header, the server won't be able to read the request properly. `curl` will set this header for you, if you don't override it, so don't.

Comment: So, basically request payload is just a postfields?

Comment: @Andra yeah, the request payload is what you put in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. you can read the specs about how the headers and body are separated here https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616 (specifically section 4), but the gist of it is `headers are separated by \r\n, the headers are separated from the body with \r\n\r\n, and the body is optional`

Comment: I've do everything you said, but still got 403 :/

Comment: @Andra are you sure that cookies.txt actually contains the cookies received during extraction of the csrf token prior to your CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE call?

Comment: @Andra if your cookies are modified in either of those 2 requests, it breaks the code, that may very well be the problem. also, hard-coding cookie session ids is generally just a bad idea, usually those ids have a limited lifespan, and the session id will be invalid in just a few hours, or days.

Comment: Check my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out using [Postman](http://getpostman.com).

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://admin-official.line.me/11702069/home/api/objects",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    "csrf_token" => $split2[0],
    "file" => new CURLFile("test.jpg")
  ),
  //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"csrf_token\"\r\n\r\nETukCyg_-OM72cZ0MuAyunvvy4cb8Cx2QqoP41T7\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: */*",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,id;q=0.8,de-DE;q=0.7,de;q=0.6",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
    "Cookie: tzoffset=-420; _trmccid=6b030cba93d9db09; _ga=GA1.2.1058855825.1526457491; _gid=GA1.2.814129237.1526457491; ldsuid=CiDum1r75zWBJ3f7oLqRAg==; _trmcdisabled2=-1; _trmcuser=^{^\^id^^:^\^^^^}; _ga=GA1.3.1058855825.1526457491; _gid=GA1.3.814129237.1526457491; plack_session_localaccount=COOKIE; minesota=COOKIE; minesota2=COOKIE; _trmcsession=^{^\^id^^:^\^36b6efe6^^,^\^path^^:^\^/11702069/home/send/^^,^\^query^^:^\^^^,^\^time^^:1526880852499,^\^_dice^^:0.4099096438552394^}; plack_session=519cce226206bd15cba86f2153c9dc91a56df4fb; _trmcpage=/11702069/home/send/; __try__=1526881572577",
    "Origin: https://admin-official.line.me",
    "Postman-Token: 8b9dc9c8-166a-4c50-93c4-b16ca72d72dc",
    "Referer: https://admin-official.line.me/11702069/home/send/",
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36",
    //"content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
  ),
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```